# Realm - filter objects greater than string attribute

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

I am trying to filter objects from Realm database. I have attribute `itemIdForDateOrder` which is string (looks something like this: `11e6-eef3-09306910-baa7-417b3207abf6`) and I have no problem with sorting by this attribute:

```
realm.objects(ItemInfo.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "itemIdForDateOrder", ascending: false)
```

Problem is that I am trying to filter objects by this attribute and I want to get objects that has this parameter greater.

Part of my predicate:

```
if let item = newerThan {
   formatString += " AND itemIdForDateOrder > '" + item.itemIdForDateOrder + "'"
}
```

But when I used it I get exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid operator type',
>   reason: 'Operator '>' not supported for string type'

But comparing is working for string types when I can user my attribute with sort. So is there a way how can I filter by this attribute as well? Or I must get all objects and then filtered them (not by realm predicate filter). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, Realm's query engine does not currently support filtering string properties using inequalities. I'd suggest [filing an enhancement request against Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new) requesting that such support be added, and then performing the filtering outside of Realm (i.e., gather the objects into an array and then filter the array).

Comment: Thanks for anwer. I created solution with filtering outside of Realm. Just wondering if there is a way with Realm. For now no so I fill enhancement request.